# Kafka data loss, in producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have been trying to configure one Kafka broker, one topic, one producer, one consumer.
when producer produces , if the Broker goes down, loss of data happens, 
eg:

```
In Buffer:
Datum 1 - published
Datum 2 - published
.
. ---->(Broker goes down for a while and reconnects...)
.
Datum 4 - published
Datum 5 - published
```

Properties Configured for Producer are:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
acks=all
retries=1
batch.size=16384
linger.ms=2
buffer.memory=33554432
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer
value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
producer.type=sync
buffer.size=102400
reconnect.interval=30000
request.required.acks=1
```

The data size lesser than the configured buffer size..
Help me know where I am going wrong...!

Comment: Not sure what do exactly do. I would assume that the messages you try to write to Kafka while broker is done are not acked by Kafka. If a message is not acked, it indicates that the message was not written to Kafka and producer need to re-try to write the message.

Comment: yes, the solution was, retry as many times as we can, until broker comesup, so the last offset will commit and the retry values will be written to the broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you exactly do. I would assume that the messages you try to write to Kafka while broker is down are not acked by Kafka. If a message is not acked, it indicates that the message was not written to Kafka and producer needs to re-try to write the message.

The easiest way to do this, is by setting the configuration parameters `retries` and `retry.backoff.ms` accordingly.

At application level, you can also register a `Callback` in `send(..., Callback)` to get informed about success/failure. In case of failure, you could retry sending by calling `send()` again.